# How to make FBML comment box post to my website FB page not my personal page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, fbml, facebook-wall

I am attempting to use an FBML comment box on my website so that it will post comments to my FB page associated with my website and not my personal FB page.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is:

Use the Comments Plug in at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Set up your comments link by completing all the boxes to meet your needs.

As you do this an example of how your comments box will look on your web site appears below the set up box. In that example you will see

Posting as Stephen Coulson (Change)

next to the comment box.

click change.  A pull down menu enables you to switch to your FB page.

Hope this answers your question